# Transition from xib with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am learning the Swift on lessons and have such a project: http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

The structure of the project
[image: The structure of the project]

Base Class
[image: Base Class]

So it looks on an emulator
[image: So it looks on an emulator]

I want to click a button "Press me" and go to another View via Navigation Controller (where to be the back button) like this (best if it will be normally on Main.storyboard):
[image]

Is it real? Any solutions please?
Project on github: https://github.com/PaulSolt/CustomViewFromXib

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `viewDidLoad` method of ViewController

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = "Press Me"
```

But I suggested you according to my experience, create your own back button and handle it yourself.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Press Me", style:.Plain, target:nil, action:"backButtonPressed")
}

func backButtonPressed()
{
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```